# name column in user table not indexable anymore?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I trying execute next FQL query

`SELECT uid FROM user WHERE name='Vovka'`

and getting
`(#604) Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql"`

but earlier this kind of query worked fine, and there
 `http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/` 
the name column also marked as indexable.

Tell me please what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks, Volodymyr.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a currently (2010-10-29) open bug in Facebook's bug tracker - see https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/266794040030851 for the status

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to use the Graph API

```
$facebook->api("/search?q=".urlencode($name)."&type=user");
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Igy, this was bug. It closed as **wontfix** 5 years ago.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/403840696324085/