# Search Facebook using PHP SDK

Tags: search, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

In the last days, I'm working on the application which needs to search for users on Facebook. Since the FQL query for ["username" was deprecated/canceled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900732/name-column-in-user-table-not-indexable-anymore), I have decided to use common search API.

I use PHP so [FB PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk) is the way I'd prefer. I have used it earlier for FQL queries, just like this:

```
// $api is already initialized, with access_key, app secret and so on
$users = $api(array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => "SELECT first_name,last_name FROM user WHERE uid='12345'",
));
```

I'd like to build the search query in the similar way. Especially, I don't want to urlencode the parameters, specify access key, app secret and all the stuff the SDK is supposed to do for me. However, I haven't been able to build this query using SDK yet. Is there any possibility to do it? If yes, how? I have found long list of sdk-supported "api calls" but I need to build the query for graph.facebook.com/search?arguments.

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT: To make it clear, I don't want to build the string by myself. I know this solution works. But imho it's ugly when I have SDK:

```
$name = urlencode(trim($first_name . " " . $last_name_));
$users = $this->facebook->api("/search?q=$name&type=user&access_token=$key");
```

Comment: For all the graph api search functions you will need to urlencode the search strings, the SDK does not do it for you.  Optionally you would post a request to facebook to add.

Comment: Also NOTE:  because of different levels of permission, there are different types of access_tokens, so the user has to provide the token to the sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Searching User via Graph API using php-sdk 3.1.1

- User will need to authorize your app before making a search for
  users.

---

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}
```

---

- Php-skd 3.1.1 init.

---

```
<?php 
require './src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'your-app-id',
  'secret' => 'your-app-secret',
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

/*  */
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
?>
```

---

- Search includes, encoding search term, setting results limit, and
  offset for paging.

---

```
    <?php 
    /* Get Search parameter from url or post and urlencode it. */
$q = urlencode($_GET['qs']);
if(!$_GET['qs']){
$q = urlencode($_POST['qs']);
    if(!$_POST['qs']){
            /* Default Search Term */
    $q = "Shawn+E+Carter";
    }
}
    /* Get Results Limit from url or set default. */
$limit = $_GET['limit'];
    if (!$_GET['limit']){
$limit = 60;
    }
    /* Get Offset from url or set default for paging. */
$offset = $_GET['offset'];
    if (!$_GET['offset']){
$offset = 0;
}
    /* Make Graph API call to user */
$usersearch = 'search%3Fq='.$q.'%26type=user%26limit='.$limit.'%26offset='.$offset.'';

    echo '<pre style="text-align: left;">';
    print_r($usersearch);
    echo '</pre>';
    ?>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I DON'T want to do. Urlencode and build the string by myself. You even don't use the SDK, do you?

Comment: Yes i use the sdk, and the search string has to be urlencoded or it will error.  I use this same method in my page search function for my plugin - sample here https://shawnsspace.com/plugins/TimeLineSearch.php?pageid=135669679827333&since=900+days+ago&until=now&limit=8&type=posts&fh=800&qs=beach+resort

Comment: I am sorry, could you specify the line where you use it? I really can't see it. However, url encoding should be handled by SDK. And building the query string as well, that's my point.

Comment: If you are referring to the sdk, i handle that before my <html> tag in my documents.  As per the search, i use a basic form with method post.